# Input selection for dry contact vs pnp

Tags: input

On my board I have to acquire dozens of input digital signals. Each one might be a dry contact or pnp (12V). I have to isolate them from the MCU side.

The basic circuits could be:

**dry contact**: pull-up resistor to 12V and input across the optocoupler diode

**pnp input**: series resistor and input between the other end of the resistor and GND

What could be a simple circuit to handle both configurations? It's ok a front-end compatible with both or a single dip-switch to select.

Answer (score 1):

If the dry contact is floating, just wire it as if it were a PNP - now you are analyzing a single type of input - a contact (or BJT) that pulls-up to 12 volts.

I would use an opto with its LED in series with a current limiting resistor and connect this between PNP (or dry contact connected to 12 volts) and ground: -
[image]

If you can't take the dry contact to 12 volts then you can still use the opto method but the anode of the opto would connect to 12 volts and the resistor (R1) would connect to the dry contact (or NPN equivalent).

R1 is chosen so that about 20 mA flows when the dry contact or PNP closes.

Comment: The drawback is I need a third connection: gnd, anode and 12V. pnp goes between gnd and anode, while dry contact between anode and 12V. **EDIT**: sorry, now I understand what you mean: EITHER contact or pnp go between the two indicated points!

Comment: Usually the pnp is internally connected to the 12V and only the collector is available along the ground ref. This is the reason of my comment above.

Comment: A PNP output would naturally go between positive rail and anode. An NPN output would go between ground and resistor. I'm saying this because I'm unsure about what you are saying in your comment. I think you need to be clear about what you do understand and don't understand. The same circuit suits either PNP or NPN. A dry contact can replace PNP or NPN but you need a power rail for a dry contact.

Comment: I apologize, English is not my primary language. I mean that pnp outputs of common devices expose only the collector: https://www.optex-fa.com/img/tech_guide/photo_sensor/control_output02.png Hence, it's not possible to wire it as per your schematic.

Comment: So, for a PNP, you get collector (output) and ground yes? If yes then of course you can wire it; R1 connects to ground and anode connects to collector.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I tried to say in the first comment. Dry contact instead would connect between anode and +12V: hence three pins needed (ground, anode and +12V)

Comment: For any dry contact you will need a power source so three connections are needed; one to supply voltage, a 2nd for the on/off signal and a third to measure against/draw current (0 volts).

Answer (score 0):

The circuit below should do what you've described.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg3MBZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 limits the input current to 10 mA at 12 V with around 2 V drop across the opto-isolator's IRLED. You can change R1 to provide a suitable current for the the opto-isolator you choose. D2 protects the IRLED against an accidental reverse voltage, as all of the IRLEDs I've used can only handle a couple of volts reverse-biased before they're damaged.

R2 may also change value to suit your opto-isolator and MCU input leakage current.

Comment: I don't undestand how it would work with a dry contact between sw pins. No pull-up is provided, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Mark, revised to show your PNP or switch ('dry contact', as you call it).